# How do I force x11vnc to stream lower quality?

Tags: remote, vnc, remote-desktop, remote-control, x11vnc

I need to access a remote machine via a high latency, slow connection. It uses `x11vnc` and I want it to broadcast video in much lower quality than what's actually on the screen. First thing that comes to mind is to use less colours (e.g. 8 bit), but it can be anything, as long as the remote machine is responsive even though it may, for example, show a large rich-colour desktop image (which I don't need to see anyway). Something [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/411058/setting-up-tightvnc-for-8-bit-pixels), except for `x11vnc`.

I will, however, appreciate keeping all the text sharp because, I work with the terminal.

Here's what I tried:

- use `-notruecolor`, found here http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html
- use `-speeds dsl`, found here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1331555
- try setting 8 bit video using `-rawfb`, found here https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc
- enable `-ncache 10` as per https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/high-latency-vnc-tech-support/, but got [this issue](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/issues/525)

I'm using the built-in Screen Sharing app, which [seems to be almost the only option](http://web.archive.org/web/20180324015551/http://www.davidtheexpert.com/post.php?id=5) on Mac OS.

I'm out of ideas. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on the VNC client side, rather than server side.

As for Mac alernatives, try [VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/macos/) or [UltraVNC](https://www.uvnc.com/).

Both are good, fast and configurable.